# slider on swatch wootheme not working in wordpress

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-slider

I use swatch free theme of wootheme in my wordpress site.
I update wootheme framework to last version.
add new slide in slide tab but when i add another slide, slider on home page not working.
how can i solve this problem.

I download swatch free theme from [here](http://www.woothemes.com/2011/08/swatch/)

thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem.
Here's the solution. 
Go to your admin panel and change the permission of the map :
publich_html/(yoursite.com)/wp_content/themes/swatch/cache to 777

Answer (score 0):

If you already have followed instructions given in documentation then you should look into
Swatch>> Theme Option>> Homepage Slider.

Increasing "Slider Entries" might solve your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

First change the permission of the map : `publich_html/(yoursite.com)/wp_content/themes/swatch/cache` to `777`.

Also must see `Swatch>> Theme Option>> Homepage Slider`.

If it is still not solved then delete old slides and create new. My problem was solved in this way.